# Why Kotlin do not allow any code in primary constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin

It cause inconvenience when work with code blelow

```
abstract class View {
    abstract fun findViewById(id: Int): View
    abstract fun setOnClickListener(listener: (View) -> Boolean)
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) {
    init {
        child1.setOnClickListener { false }
    }
    val child1 = itemView.findViewById(1)
    val child2 = itemView.findViewById(2)
}
```

The compiler complains that:

```
Kotlin: Variable 'child1' must be initialized
```

So I have to add an additional function and call it every time after construction:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) {
    val child1 = itemView.findViewById(1)
    val child2 = itemView.findViewById(2)

    fun bindEventHandlers() {
        child1.setOnClickListener { false }
    }
}

val vh = ViewHolder(v)
vh.bindEventHandlers()
```

So, is there any convenient way to do init things like this? This often happens when work with Android RecyclerView & ListView.

Comment: Marvin, the answer below appears to answer your question, did you try this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define your properties before your `init` block -

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) {
    val child1 = itemView.findViewById(1)
    val child2 = itemView.findViewById(2)

    init {
        child1.setOnClickListener { false }
    }
}
```

Comment: Marvin did not have an init block -- it seems he did not realize that init blocks are the Kotlin Way. But that solves his problem without answering the question: why does Kotlin require forbidding code in the body of the constructor, requiring the programmer to put it all in an init block instead?